# Message pop-up window on all open instances

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# WPF that is a database form. Multiple users have the same form application open in multiple instances. Is there a way to add a button that displays a message window on the other instances too?

Comment: Yes... signalR (for the win)

Comment: What is the reason for the _winforms_ tag?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to solve this is to create an independent service that will publish events. All clients should listen to those events and display the popup (or react how they want as a result).
There are many ways of communication to create this Client-Server interaction, one could be WCF.

If all "users" are on the same process, it could be an internal service shared by all view-models, that raises simple  .Net events. That Service could be shared as a singletone or by MEF for example.